# как скрыть данные php

Tags: php, yii2

у меня есть таблица с данными пользователей, и у каждого есть дата окончания. если у пользователя пройдет 5 дней после даты окончания то его данные должны скрыться но в базе должна остаться

Comment: Где скрыться? Если с грида, то просто условие в билдер добавьте where и всё

Comment: можно на примере?

Answer (score 0):

В запросе, при подготовке дата провайдера добавьте фильтр методом

```
andWhere(['between', 'date', \date('Y-m-d', strtotime(\date("Y-m-d") . "-5 days")), \date("Y-m-d") ]);
```